# Retrieval of saved data of checkboxlist in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, .net

I have designed one form which is having `Checkboxlist`.This form is for assigning time slots to class and division ie (slot1 for 1st_A,1st_B)

I have bind data to `Checkboxlist` from two different tables `(i.e  class and division)` .

At the `page_load` event I have bind **Chekboxlist**, then user can select `class_division` for the time slot. Then on clicking save button I am only saving selected `Checkbox` data in another table.

The problem is when user run the form for first time user can select any class_division for particular time slot.But when user selects another time slot then the `Checkbox` which are already selected for another slot should be selected and disabled first so that the user can select from remaining `class_division`.

Answer (score 0):

After saving the data, you can make the division slot to be **disabled**

```
CheckBoxList1.Items[i].Enabled = false; 
CheckBoxList1.Items[i].Selected = false;
```